# Firebase - snapshot.val() is returning null - Why is it not able to connect to the right collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve information from a field inside my firebase collection so I can use that information on my site. However, snapshot.val() is giving me null. Is my reference not targeting the collection correctly? When I try to access the field inside the collection (as you can see me doing in the line commented out) I get this error:

> headerNav.vue?c47a:69 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'userControl' of null

[this is an image of how my database is set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loURo.jpg)

This problem singlehandedly made me get a StackOverflow account. Can any of you make sense of it? I would love to be shown to be an idiot if you can just teach me how to fix this.

```
  if(firebase.auth().currentUser){

    return firebase.database().ref('/users/samgmailcom').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
      //console.log(snapshot.val().userControl);
    });

  } else {
    this.user = null
  }
```

Comment: Try to remove the first "/" in the reference

Comment: Already tried that. It did not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database you show in your screenshot is Cloud Firestore. But the API you're accessing is for the Firebase Realtime Database. They are completely separate databases, each with their own API.

Follow the documentation on [getting data from Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) to fix the problem. Something like this should do the trick:

```
var docRef = db.collection("users").doc("samgmailcom");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Comment: Holy shit, that totally worked. I can't believe it never occurred to me that the cloud firebase would need a different way of targeting it since I had to choose between one of them when I set it up. It makes perfect sense when you point it out, but I still would have wished that the documentation for the regular firebase would have said something about that though - because I feel like that was not obvious. 

Like, this is the documentation I was reading: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

I just interpreted "database" in this context to mean any database.

Comment: I just upvoted your answer but apparently my upvote wont be displayed because I am to new on the site :(

Comment: Thanks, just did :)